# When Promise.then() hooks are called?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I observe deferring of completeness notifications in Firefox's promises. Following assertion fails, because onFullfilled() is called too late<sup>*</sup>.

```
var resolved = false;
function onFullfilled() {
    resolved = true;
    log("Completed");
}
Promise.resolve(true).then(onFullfilled);
assert(resolved, "Promise completed promise should call resolution hook immediately.");
```

When exactly onFullfilled() is guaranteed to be called on Promise resolution?

<sub>* In my case "Completed" log message appears after test framework report assertion failure.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promise resolution hooks are *always* called *after* all sync code is executed. This is by design - and is done in order to prevent race conditions.

Since promises sometimes resolve asynchronously the specification mandates they are *always* resolved asynchronously so the same code path executes. Promises guard you [against Zalgo](http://blog.izs.me/post/59142742143/designing-apis-for-asynchrony).

It is [specified here](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-34):

> onFulfilled or onRejected must not be called until the execution context stack contains only platform code.

A lot of test frameworks - namely Mocha support testing promises directly with promise-syntax - by returning a promise.

```
it("does something", function(){
    return aPromise; // if aPromise resolves the test passes
})
```

Comment: hi @Benjamin Gruenbaum +1 -  Does this basically mean that the main JavaScript thread has to finish all its code first to execute the promises and async functions?

Comment: only then will the call stack be empty, right? @Benjamin Gruenbaum

Comment: yes. That's exactly what it means.

Comment: Excellent @Benjamin Gruenbaum +1

Answer (score -2):

You should always give a function to "then". So you should use "onFullfilled()" instead of "onFullfilled" as parameter of "then".

So it should be like:

Promise.resolve(true).then(onFullfilled());

Comment: No, `.then(onFulfilled)` is correct. `onFulfilled` is a function. `onFulfilled()` is a function call.