# Javascript Promise Guarantees - Javascript Event Loop

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

In the Mozilla `Promise` documentation, there is a Guarantees section:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Guarantees

It contains the following statement:

> Unlike "old-style", passed-in callbacks, a promise comes with some guarantees:
>
> Callbacks will never be called before the completion of the current
> run of the JavaScript event loop.

This makes sense to me and is the behavior I would expect, but I'm looking for some additional documentation supporting this "Guarantee".

Is there some sort of spec that explicitly documents / requires this? Is this guaranteed for any javascript runtime that provides a native Promise implementation? Is it the wild west, and you can't depend on it, etc.

Comment: If only there were [some kind of spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) that defined how ECMAScript and its built-in features worked.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29454966/1048572, https://stackoverflow.com/q/23447876/1048572

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there some sort of spec that explicitly documents / requires this?

The spec used by promise libraries is the promise A+ spec. This particular requirement is [number 2.2.4](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-34). Pretty much any promise library you use will obey this, though if you need to check this, there are [tests which can verify compliance with the spec](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-tests)

More importantly, now that promises are a part of the language, native promises are governed by the ECMAScript specifications. Promises were first introduced in the 2015 edition, in [section 25.4](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-objects). The latest completed edition as of the time of this answer is the [2018 edition](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/). The specific behavior you asked about is due to the section governing the `.then` method ([found here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-performpromisethen)), and the section on triggerPromiseReaction ([found here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-triggerpromisereactions)). Each of those in turn references the enqueueJob operation ([found here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-enqueuejob))

Comment: ECMAScript's behavior is bound by the ECMAScript spec, not Promises/A+, and the former makes no mention of the latter. So the second half of your question is the vital part.

Comment: Also ES2015 might have been the first edition of the spec to describe promises, but it has since been superseded 3 times by newer versions. You might want to refer to the current normative specification.

Comment: Thanks, i've incorporated both of your feedback :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some sort of spec that explicitly documents / requires this?

Yes, the [Promises/A+ interoperability spec](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-34) requires this.

But no, that document is not normative for the native `Promise` implementation.

> Is this guaranteed for any javascript runtime that provides a native Promise implementation?

Yes. This feature is an implicit property of the scheduling behaviour detailed in the ECMAScript specification for the native `Promise` object.

> Is it the wild west, and you can't depend on it?

You can and should depend it. Even most non-native promise implementation guarantee this due to the popularity of the Promises/A+ spec.

Answer (score 1):

As with any built-in ECMAScript feature, the behavior of native promises is defined in the [ECMAScript Spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/).

The relevant sections in the 9th edition spec are [section 25.6.5.4.1](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-enqueuejob), which defines the behavior of the `.then` method, and [section 8.4.1](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-enqueuejob), which describes the EnqueueJob operation (which is used when `.then` is called on an already-resolved promise).